Led spot light drivers plugged with no lights connected
So i've been questioning myself about led drivers. My neighbor finds that my led recessed lights on the side of my garage are to bright. Instead of disconnecting the drivers from my circuit I was thinking of disconnecting the led lights from the drivers which would leave the drivers powered but no lights connected to it. I was wondering if unplugging the led lights but leaving the drivers plugged to my circuit will damage the drivers in the long run?
Thanks

A well-designed driver should not suffer (or cause) any damage when powered with no LEDs connected. But we have no way of knowing if yours are well-designed or not. It would be safer to disconnect the drivers.
